# identify changes between the 2 tables (month1, month2). I'm using union/intersect/except

Tags: sql-server, union, intersect, except

the results return random order.  table month1, month2 for most records but mixed in records returned month2, month1.  i need consistent month1, month2.  I've seen many replies to something similar, but nothing is working.  I've tried cte, sub queries, I've added 1 to month1 and 2 to month2 *but* results see that as a 'change' and returns all records.  my actual table has over 5000 records so not sure with this small group you will see the same sort issue that I'm having.

expected results would be 2 rows, both the Bob Marley rows, as the 3rd column changed from one month to the other.  the union/intersect/except does accomplish this, but the results do not consistently display as table a, table b.  every once in a while records will be in table b, table a order.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            column1,
            column2,
            column3,
            1 AS sortby
        FROM
            tbl_Month1
        UNION
        SELECT
            column1,
            column2,
            column3,
            0 AS sortby
        FROM
            tbl_Month2
        INTERSECT
        SELECT
            column1,
            column2,
            column3,
            1 AS sortby
        FROM
            tbl_Month1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT
            column1,
            column2,
            column3,
            0 AS sortby
        FROM
            tbl_Month2
    ) results
ORDER BY
    column1,
    column2
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE #month1 (
    id INT
    , name NVARCHAR(200)
    , value_changed nvarchar(10)
    )

CREATE TABLE #month2 (
    id INT
    , name NVARCHAR(200)
    , value_changed nvarchar(10)
    )

INSERT INTO #month1 (id, name, value_changed)
VALUES (12345, 'Bob Marley','11233456')
, (12346, 'Bob Seger','55223366')
, (12346, 'Bob Dylan','47895645')
, (12346, 'Bob Plant','74185296')

INSERT INTO #month2 (id, name, value_changed)
VALUES (12345, 'Bob Marley','32565221')
, (12346, 'Bob Seger','55223366')
, (12346, 'Bob Dylan','47895645')
, (12346, 'Bob Plant','74185296')
```

Comment: Can you please share table structure and sample data. You can mail me if you want.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: B intersect A except B will only return A except B. Will you please share your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned when you are adding sortBy column 0 to tbl_month2 and 1 to tbl_month1 then  no rows from those two tables are gonna intersect.

But If you remove sortby column it doesn't make sense either.
Your are using intersect on tbl_Month2 and tbl_Month1 which will return all the common rows then you are doing union with tbl_Month1 which will eventually return all the rows from tbl_month1 only. Then you have excepted tbl_month2 from it.

So the condition became just tbl_Month1 except tbl_month2. Is it what are you looking for?
Then you can use not exists instead of except as below:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id , name , value_changed, 0 as sortby FROM tbl_Month1 tm

where not exists(SELECT id
    , name
    , value_changed
    , 1 as sortby
FROM tbl_Month2 tbm where tbm.id=tm.id and tbm.name=tm.name and tbm.value_changed=tm.value_changed)

) results
ORDER BY id , name ,sortby
```

Comment: thank you for the help.   i tried this query on the real tables and it doesn't return the same # of records as expected.  106 legit record changes  vs 40 with the above scenario.